# PHP Grouping / Totalling

Tags: php, grouping

I'm really stuck for ideas on how to do this, so I'm not exactly sure what to ask for, but here goes.

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach($order as $key => $ord){
   $attribute =  explode(":", $order[$key]);    
   echo sku($attribute[0],$attribute[2],$attribute[1],$attribute[4])." - ".$attribute[3].";    
}
```

The output of this will be something like

```
SKU - QUANTITY
1001-01 - 5
1001-02 - 3
1001-01 - 1
1045-02 - 1
1001-02 - 8
1001-01 - 3
1003-01 - 4
```

I need a way of totalling these so it shows

```
SKU - QUANTITY
1001-01 - 9
1001-02 - 11
1003-01 - 4
1045-02 - 1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Just use an array with the sku as the key:

```
$totals = array();

foreach($order as $ord){
   $attribute =  explode(":", $ord);    

   $sku = sku($attribute[0],$attribute[2],$attribute[1],$attribute[4])

   $amt = $attribute[3];

    if (isset($totals[$sku])) {
        $totals[$sku] += $amt;
    } else {
        $totals[$sku] = $amt;
    }

}
```

On a side note: `explode` being required to do things like this often implies that the data is not being stored in the proper format.

Also, `$order[$key]` is the exact same thing as `$ord`, so I'm not sure why you're using `$order[$key]`.